# The text with the attached file is not sent to Discord in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, discord, guzzle

My task is to send a signed file to Discord private messages. I use `php 7.2`, `Laravel 5.8` and `Guzzle 7.0`. The file (PDF) is stored on the server.

```
$discordBaseUrl = 'https://discord.com/api';
$channelId = '1882390272832675344';
$payroll = [
    'source' => 'C:\Users\Schizo\source\web\sd\storage\app\payrolls\306_payroll.pdf',
];

$httpClient = new Client([
    'verify' => false,
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => config('local.discord_token'),
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);

$httpClient->post("$discordBaseUrl/channels/$channelId/messages", [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ],
    'body' => json_encode([
        'content' => 'A payroll has been sent to you.',
        'file' => curl_file_create(
            realpath($payroll['source']),
            'application/pdf',
            pathinfo($payroll['source'])['filename']
        )
    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
])->getBody()->getContents();
```

If you change the header to `application/json` and leave only `content`, then the text without the file is sent normally. Trying to execute the request provided in the block above, I get an error:

> Client error: `POST https://discord.com/api/channels/1882390272832675344/messages` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}

I tried to use the `attachments` field with the header `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload_json"` (see below), as shown in the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files), but this also did not give the desired result.

```
$httpClient->post("$discordBaseUrl/channels/$channelId/messages", [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'form-data; name="payload_json"',
    ],
    'body' => json_encode([
        'content' => 'A payroll has been sent to you.',
        'attachments' => [
            (object)[
                'id' => 0,
                'description' => 'Payroll description.',
                'filename' => realpath($payroll['source']),
            ],
        ],
    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
])->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: You can not say the content-type was `multipart/form-data`, and then send something else (JSON) - of course that won't work. As for what you tried regarding `payload_json` - show code, instead of giving only a vague verbal description.

Comment: @CBroe I added the code snippet I was talking about.

Comment: That is wrong all over. For starters, you are again sending a JSON-encoded body, but pretend the content type was `multipart/form-data`. And the `Content-Disposition` does not need to be set as a request header for the whole request - it needs to be part of the request _body_. You need to make a multipart request  with one of the parameters named `payload_json` containing your JSON, and a second parameter named `files[0]`, that contains your file upload.

Comment: @CBroe Do you mean this option, or did I misunderstand you? https://pastebin.com/bYi0qLVQ

Comment: You are _still_ trying to pass off a JSON-encoded body as `multipart/form-data` there, so right now I can only get the impression, that you are not understanding _anything_ I tried to tell you ...?

Comment: You'll need something like `'body' => ['payload_json' => json_encode(...), 'files[0]' => curl_file_create(...)` And what data you actually have to put into the payload_json, should be clear from the example in the documentation.

Comment: Looking at your tech stack, I'd suggest you first update and then see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

```
$httpClient->post("$discordBaseUrl/channels/$channelId/messages", [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => 'content',
            'contents' => 'A payroll has been sent to you.',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'files[0]',
            'filename' => pathinfo($payroll['source'])['basename'],
            'Mime-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'contents' => fopen(realpath($payroll['source']), 'r'),
        ],
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents();
```